Download password protected file from sftp server
I am trying to download a password protected .zip file from a password protected server into R. But I am not succeeding.
I first read in the filenames from the server
url<-"<url>"
userpwd<-"<username:password>"
filenames <- getURL(url, userpwd)

Then I use the url for the first .zip file
filename1<-paste0(url,strsplit(filenames, "\n")[[1]][2])
ftp_data1 <- getURL(filename1, userpwd)

-> But this gives an error
Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
  embedded nul in string: 'PK\003\004\024'

I used this code instead; from an advice found at
sftp get files with R
bin <- getBinaryURL(filename1, userpwd=userpwd)
con <- file("<output.zip>", open = "wb")
writeBin(bin, con)
close(con)

This does show a .zip file with the names of the .csv files that I need
However, I cannot open these files
If I use the same code to download a file that is not password protected it does work
So the password-protection seems to be the issue, but how do I feed another password?

Downloading a password protected ZIP file should be no different to downloading any other file. SFTP does not care what the file content is. Unless you have have some very specialized SFTP server. And then you would see the difference with any other SFTP client. Do you?

But it is. When I download a non-password protected zip-file it is not problem, but when I download the password-protected zip-file opening the .zip gives an unspecified error. So, apparently it has to do with the fact that the .zip file is password protected.

You didn't answer my question. If you download the protected file with any commandline/GUI FTP, can you open it? If you can, did you check how does it differ to the file downloaded with your R code?

What do you mean by "with any commandline/GUI FTP,"?

I've meant any "FTP client".

I can download the password protected .zip file through another program and then I can access the files. The size of the files is larger than what I download with the combination getBinaryURL() and writeBin() functions. I don't know what else to look for.

I still do not think it's a password problem. It's rather incomplete download problem. Were't the unprotected files that you have tried smaller than the protected one?
